# How can I get information on EventBridge Pipes errors?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-event-bridge

I can see that an EventBridge Pipe is failing (see screenshot), but I can't see a way to get information on the error. I can't see any cloudwatch group. What is the mechanism to see the details of each EventBridge error (or success)?

[image]